# Linear algebra solution uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra

$$x_1 + fx_2 = R$$ $$gx_1+hx_2 = S$$

For what values of $f, g, h, R, S$ is the solution unique? Does your answer depend on all five parameters?

Although I think I've done a good portion of the work, I don't really understand how to determine the answer to the questions posed at the beginning. How do I determine for what values of $f, g, h, R, S$ the solution of the system is unique? How do I determine whether it depends on all five parameters? Any help is appreciated very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an excerpt from Artin's Algebra:
[image]

The solution of the system of linear equations will be unique if and only if the determinant of the coefficient matrix is nonzero. The coefficient matrix is given by:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant of this matrix is

$$\det(A) = d - bc$$

Therefore, the solution of the system will be unique if and only if $d - bc \neq 0$. Note that the values of $K$ and $L$ do not affect the uniqueness of the solution. They can take any real values, and it won't change the condition for a unique solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can represent this as a matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\\ x_2\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}K\\\ L\end{bmatrix} \text{ or abstractly as } A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$$

For this system to be unique, we need to be able to solve for the column vector $\mathbf{x}$.

We can do this by multiplying by the *inverse* of $A$ ($A^{-1}$) on both sides:

$$A^{-1}A\mathbf{x}=I\mathbf{x}=A^{-1}\mathbf{b}$$

However, to do this, we need $A$ to be *invertible* (not every matrix has an inverse).

One necessary and sufficient condition for invertibility is that $\det(A)\neq 0$, which is easy to write down for a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$$\det(A) = \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\right) = 1\cdot d - b\cdot c$$

So as long as $d \neq bc$ you have a unique solution. $K,L$ do not matter here.